# MySQL active record problem writing to newly created table

Tags: mysql, ruby, activerecord

My code is:

```
# require gems
require 'rubygems'
require 'active_record'

# Start connetion to the server
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(  
  :adapter => "mysql",  
  :host => "localhost",
  :user => "root",
  :password => "password", 
  :database => "data"
)

# Create the table
ActiveRecord::Schema.define do
  create_table :datatable do |table|
    table.column :date, :string
    table.column :word, :string
    table.column :website, :string
  end
end

class Table < ActiveRecord::Base; end

Table.create(:date => datenow, :word => someword, :website => mywebsite)
puts "code completed"
```

And I get an error when the code wants to write to the table saying:

```
path/to/mysql_adapter.rb:287:in 'query': Table 'test.tables' doesn't exist (Mysql::Error)
```

If I create a table that is called tables within the database (data) then all of my data is put into there. I want to it to be written to the table (datatable) I have just created. How can I do this and solve the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is to be expected. You're accessing a table called `table`, but creating a table called `datatable`.

To configure your `Table` model to use the `datatable` table, use [ActiveRecord::Base.set_table_name](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.0.9/ActiveRecord/Base/set_table_name/class) like so:

```
class Table < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name 'datatable'    
end
```

Alternatively, you could rename your model to Datatable.

However, I'd suggest you rename it to something entirely different. Unless you're actually storing data about tables, your model probably shouldn't be called `Table`. `WebsiteWord` comes to mind or `WordOccurrence` or perhaps just `Word`. I have a feeling it'll save you pain in the long run.

Comment: I cannot work out what syntax to use if I want to make 'datatable' a variable. so if I said datatable = "data" earlier on then what would I have to put here for it to select the table called "data". Thanks.

Comment: `datatable = "data"` makes `datatable` a variable containing the String, `"data"`. This sounds like an entirely different question, though, and I'm afraid I don't really understand what you're asking now.